# How to change back to code from html created by doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen

I batch create the documents from the code by using doxygen. However, I lost code and I didn't lose the document. I want to convert the code back from the documents. Is there any option in doxygen to do this? Thank you very much.

By the way, the documents are all html files

Comment: Does your documentation contain all your source files?  I'm not a `doxygen` expert, but doesn't it usually only contain headers?

Comment: @StephenNewell The htmls files contains all. Some files contain header code, others contain cpp code

Comment: Is this a lot of code or not ? If not just copy and paste and do some editing. If it is a lot of code, I think,  best is to write a program to read the code and output the code lines. I think a good starting point here would be python and the `HTMLParser` possibilities. Depending on the doxyen setting `STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS` you will be able to retrieve the doxygen used documentation code as well  ( when set to `NO`) otherwise you have to get reconstruct this from the rest of the documentation.

Comment: @albert, Yes it is a lot of code. If there is no other option, I will do that.

Answer (score 2):

Doxygen is a documentation generator; it's job is to go from code to documentation. As such, it has no functionality for reversing this process. Especially since the generated HTML can change from version to version.

Documentation conversion is also an inherently lossy process. Unless you outputted all of your source code into the documentation, you're not going to be able to reconstruct everything. The best you might do is rebuild most aspects of some headers, but even then, anything that goes undocumented (like header include files and such) won't be in the HTML.

Comment: DocBook ? How does this answer the question,. It just gives some background.

Comment: The OP asked about Doxygen, not DocBook.

Comment: @albert: Sorry, wrong word. The rest is still true though.